# Why cannot I display particles on the webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am trying to display particles on my screen, and then animate them in a way. Like just moving around and boucing on the screen. I cannot find the error which does not allow me to display these particles.

Best regards,
Tar2ed

```js
// Initializing the canvas
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var c = canvas.getContext('2d');

// Setting the positition in the middle of the canvas
var posX = 512,
  posY = 384;

// Creation of an array of particles
var particles = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
  particles.push(new Particle());
}

// Creation of a fucntion which will help us create multiple particles
function Particle() {

  // Randomizing the position on the canvas
  this.posX = Math.random() * canvas.width;
  this.posY = Math.random() * canvas.height;
}

// Creating a draw function
function draw() {

  // Painting the canvas in black
  c.fillStyle = "black";
  c.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  for (var d = 0; d < Particle.length; d++) {
    var p = particles[d];

    // Creating the particle
    c.beginPath();
    c.fillStyle = "white";
    c.arc(p.posX, p.posY, 5, Math.PI * 2, false);
    c.fill();

    // Incrementing the X and Y postition
    p.posX++;
    p.posY++;
  };
}

// Drawing the particle
setInterval(draw, 33);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In the for-loop: `Particle.length` should be `particles.length`.
2. The arguments for `c.arc` are wrong. They should be: `c.arc(p.posX, p.posY, 5, 0, Math.PI * 2);`
3. You should consider utilizing `window​.request​Animation​Frame()` for calling the draw-loop.

Demo from your example:

```js
// Initializing the canvas
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var c = canvas.getContext('2d');

// Setting the positition in the middle of the canvas
var posX = 512,
    posY = 384;

// Creation of an array of particles
var particles = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++ ){
  particles.push(new Particle());
}

// Creation of a fucntion which will help us create multiple particles
function Particle() {

  // Randomizing the position on the canvas
  this.posX = Math.random() * canvas.width;
  this.posY = Math.random() * canvas.height;
}

// Creating a draw function
function draw() {

  // Painting the canvas in black
  c.fillStyle = "black";
  c.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  for (var d = 0; d < particles.length; d++) {
    var p = particles[d];

    // Creating the particle
    c.beginPath();
    c.fillStyle = "white";
    c.arc(p.posX, p.posY, 5, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    c.fill();

    // Incrementing the X and Y postition
    p.posX++;
    p.posY++;
  }
}

// Drawing the particle
setInterval(draw, 33);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="310" height="160">
```